# scalafmt - format long chains of infix operators

Tags: scala, scala-3, scalafmt, contextual-abstractions

I have a type declaration somewhat similar to this one:

```
type AwesomeType[F[_], X, Y] =
  Foo[F]    ?=>
  Bar[F, X] ?=>
  Baz[F, X] ?=>
  Waffle[X] ?=>
  F[Y]
```

when I run `scalafmt` with `align.preset = more`, it attempts to squeeze this chain of operators into a single line, and emits something like

```
type AwesomeType[F[_], X, Y] = Foo[F] ?=> Bar[F, X] ?=> Baz[
  F,
  X
] ?=> Waffle[X] ?=> F[Y]
```

Could anyone suggest a configuration that can cope with long chains of `?=>` infix operators?

In case that's relevant:

- in `.scalafmt.conf`:

  - `version = 3.6.1`
  - `runner.dialect = scala3`
- in `build/plugins.sbt`:

  - `addSbtPlugin("org.scalameta" % "sbt-scalafmt" % "2.4.6")`

Comment: I think your best bet would be using `format-off` - https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/docs/configuration.html#-format-off

Comment: @sarveshseri Yes, thanks, that's indeed what I'm currently using  But that's somehow a non-solution